# DataGridView Value to a textbox on an already Active Form

Tags: c#

Form1 has a text box with a button that brings up Form2 that is a filters screen for Form3 which has the DataGridView. When I doubleclick on a DataGridView Row, I need it to pass a value to the TextBox on Form1 (which will stay open and Active) I can get the correct value to display in a MessageBox when I double click the row but I can't seem to pass the value the Form1.

Form1

```
private void btnDepartmentSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
Employee_Department_Search_Filters EDSF = new Employee_Department_Search_Filters();
EDSF.Owner = this;
EDSF.Show();
```

Form2

```
private void search()
    {
        Employee_Department_Search_Results EDSR = new Employee_Department_Search_Results();
        EDSR.Owner = this.Owner;

        string departmentContains = tbDepartment.Text;

        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select uid_department, str_code AS [Department Code], str_name AS [Department Name] from tbl_department where str_name like '%" + departmentContains + "%'", conString);
        ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        adapt.Fill(ds, "Department");
        EDSR.dgvDepartmentSearch.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        EDSR.dgvDepartmentSearch.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        EDSR.dgvDepartmentSearch.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        EDSR.dgvDepartmentSearch.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        EDSR.dgvDepartmentSearch.Columns[0].Visible = false;

        this.Close();

        EDSR.ShowDialog(this.Owner);
    }
```

Form 3

```
public void rowClick()
    {
        Employee_Maintenance EM = new Employee_Maintenance();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnection);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select str_code from tbl_department where uid_department = " + dgvDepartmentSearch.SelectedCells[0].Value, conn);
        SqlDataReader read = null;
        read = comm.ExecuteReader();

        while(read.Read())
        {
            departmentCode = read["str_code"].ToString();
        }

        EM.txtDepartment.Text = departmentCode;

        conn.Close();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you should dispose of your SqlCommand and SqlDataReader objects, and use parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: You'll have to add EM.Show() if you want to see it.  Consider raising an event instead so the form can update the textbox by itself.

Comment: I don't want to open the Form again though as the form will already be active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void rowClick()
{
    // ...

    ((Employee_Maintenance)this.Owner).txtDepartment.Text = departmentCode;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: When i try this I get a System.NullReferenceException error.

Comment: This worked! I just has to change it to ((Employee_Maintenance)this.Owner) as I gave ownership of Form3 to Form1. thanks for the help!

Comment: Good for your correction! I'm going to edit the answer.